# scanf возвращает 2, неверно

Tags: c, return, scanf, stdin

Мне необходимо принять два целых числа и в случае, если в какую-либо из переменных передано неверное значение, прервать программу и вывести n/a

```
if(scanf("%i%i", &a, &b) != 2) {
     printf("n/a\n");
     return 1;
}
```

Проблема в том, что программа работает отлично, пока я не ввожу, например, "2 13.3"
В этом случае scanf все равно возвращает 2 и передает в переменную b значение 13
Однако, если ввести "13.3 2", то все работает как ожидаемо

Comment: @Эникейщик но ведь функция scanf возвращает количество успешно считанных значений, а не сами значения

Comment: да, я уже разобрался. %i - это что? целые числа это %d

Comment: @Эникейщик определяет место в командной строке для ввода целого числа 
i <- integer

Comment: нет, для ввода десятичных целых чисел используется %d.  По крайней мере в мое время использовалось. А %i это что-то другое. Попробуйте заменить на %d

Comment: @Эникейщик аналогично

Comment: "Однако, если ввести "13.3 2", то все работает как ожидаемо" - какой результат получается? Ожидаемо - это как конкретно?

Comment: Ну так всё верно работает. Когда функция встречает символ, который не является допустимым для ожидаемого типа, то она дальше не читает. Т.е. в первом случае она читает 1 и 3, потом натыкается на точку и решает,  что данные для второго числа прочитаны т.к. точка не может встречаться в целом числе и сохраняет 13. И дальше она не сможет читать целые числа, т.к. эта точка во входном потоке не даст

Comment: Что предлагаете в данном случае? я ограничен <stdio.h>

Comment: @insolor программа выводит n/a и завершает работу

Comment: `if(scanf("%i%i", &a, &b) != 2 || !isspace(getchar()))`

Comment: @EOF я не могу пользоваться ctype.h

Comment: решил тем, что имплементировал isspace() сам